# Unexpected chunk of text appeared on browser screen while working on react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, localhost, mern

I am learning MERN stack and doing a basic project on it which was running on localhost but suddenly unexpected text appeared on screen which is not allowing me to continue my work. I'm not even able to figure out what is this . Even a small hint will be helpful for me.

> lv�I��tH�#/O0� ���-A�_dk_http://localhost http://localhost
> http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js9�ɰ��H�#/[4m���0���_dk_http://localhost
> http://localhost
> http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js,�H�#/<�H�#/�HTTP/1.1
> 200 OKX-Powered-By: ExpressAccept-Ranges: bytesDate: Sun, 20 Jun 2021
> 11:38:40 GMTContent-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8ETag:
> W/"8c30-jND3gswdGsm2qbxCtnMl8V80vIc"Vary:
> Accept-EncodingContent-Encoding: gzipp �j�4�@�$��u�
> 127.0.0.1�static/js/main.chunk.js">

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was just due to cache. I tried opening it on Microsoft and it worked perfectly. SO i tried again on chrome ,but this time after clearing cache and cookies and it works !!